# アクションバーが表示されない

Tags: android

AndroidStudioでTwitterのアプリを製作しているのですが、実機で実行するとアプリのタイトルが表示されるはずのアクションバーが表示されません。
表示しない設定にはしていないはずなのですが・・・。
解決方法のご存知の方、どうかご教示ください。

実機はNexus7を使用しております。

AndroidManifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.x_vvx18.twinicooo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".TweetActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".TwitterOAuthActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="twitter"
            android:scheme="zzzakiiii" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

レイアウトxml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="179dp"></TableRow>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

//styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>
```

Comment: `AndroidManifest.xml`とレイアウトxmlを貼り付けてもらえますか？

Comment: @fkm
付け加えました！
お願いします。。。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ですが、これだけだとまだわからないので`styles.xml`も貼り付けてもらえますか？　NoActinBarのテーマになってるのかなと推測しています

Comment: @fkm 様
貼りました。
一応NoActionBar　にはしていなのですが・・・。

Comment: ここまで見る限り、問題はなさそうですな。。。うーむ

Comment: @fkm 様
アクションバーがないために、twitterアプリ製作でアクションバーに更新ボタンとつぶやきをするボタンを設定するのですが、表示させることができないんです・・・。

Comment: `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`をコールしていませんか？

Comment: @quesera2 様
コールしていません...。
調べてみたのですが、android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity　はなにかActionBarに関係ありますでしょうか・・

Comment: コメントしてくださった皆様。
無事解決しました。ありがとうございました。
ほんとうに貴重なご意見ありがとうございました！！

Comment: よろしければ、原因が何だったのか、どのようにして解決したのかをご自身で回答として投稿していただけませんか？

Answer (score 2):

AndroidManifestのandroid:ThemeをApp Themeからデフォルトに設定されているWidget.AppCompat.ActionBarに変更したところActionBarが表示されました。